# Запись данных из оконного приложения в файл библиотека tkinter

Tags: python, файлы, tkinter, filewriter

Есть задача на использование библиотеки **tkinter**: *Спроектировать и реализовать оконное приложение для заказа пиццы. Минимальные требования к приложению: наличие поля для ввода текста, наличие кнопки
для добавления заказа и записи заказа в файл.*

Мой вопрос заключается в том, как записывать в файл текст из оконного приложения. Минимальный требования для оконного приложения я выполнил следующим образом:

```
import tkinter

def click():
    entry.get()

window = tkinter.Tk()

data = tkinter.StringVar()
data.set('Заказ пиццы')

label = tkinter.Label(window, textvariable=data)
label.pack()

entry = tkinter.Entry(window)
entry.pack()

button = tkinter.Button(window, text='Добавить в заказ', command=click)    
button.pack()

button_d = tkinter.Button(window, text='Выход', command=window.destroy)
button_d.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Также я знаю как реализовывать функцию записи в файл:

```
def write_txt(data):
    with open('pizzas.txt','a') as file:
        file.write(data + '\n')
```

Но я не знаю, **как функцию записи в файл встроить в оконное приложение?**

Answer (score 2):

так у вас же все готово
просто добавьте в функцию `click()` вызов функции `write_txt(data)`

```
import tkinter

def write_txt(data):
    with open('pizzas.txt','a') as file:
        file.write(data + '\n')

def click():
    text = entry.get()
    write_txt(text)

window = tkinter.Tk()

data = tkinter.StringVar()
data.set('Заказ пиццы')

label = tkinter.Label(window, textvariable=data)
label.pack()

entry = tkinter.Entry(window)
entry.pack()

button = tkinter.Button(window, text='Добавить в заказ', command=click)    
button.pack()

button_d = tkinter.Button(window, text='Выход', command=window.destroy)
button_d.pack()
window.mainloop()
```